# Proving Continuity Theorem Least Upper Bounds - Spivak Chapter 8

Tags: calculus, continuity, upper-lower-bounds

**Theorem:** 
If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f(a)<0<f(b)$, then there is some number $x$ in $[a,b]$ such that $f(x)=0.$

**Problem 3**

**b)** The proof of the Theorem 7.1 *(the one above)*depended upon considering $A=\{x:a\leq x\leq b $, and $f(x)<0$ on $[a,x]$$  \}$ Give another proof which depends upon consideration of $B=\{x:a\leq x\leq b , f(x)<0\}$. Which point x in $[a,b]$ will this proof locate? Give an example where the sets A and B are not the same.

**What I did:**

I did very little on this part of the problem, only could come up with an example where $A\neq B$, which basically was a sine function where the point $a$ is in the region $\sin(x)<0$ and $b$ is in a region where $\sin(b)>0$, and $b-a>2\pi$.

Comment: $B$ is clearly non-empty, as it contains $a$!

Comment: Yes. Sadly, I was wrong that it finished the problem. I was reading f(x)=0 as the condition for an x to be in B... So, the problem continues :/

Comment: The proof is much the same thrust: consider the supremum of $B$. Argue using continuity from the right instead of the left.

Comment: The proof based on set $A$ gives the least value of $x$ in $[a, b] $ for which $f(x) =0$. The proof based on set $B$ gives the greatest value of $x$ in $[a, b] $ for which $f(x) =0$. To find the desired example choose a function which vanishes at two distinct points in $[a, b] $. For example consider $f(x) =(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$ on $[0,4]$. Then $A=[0, 1),B=[0,1)\cup(2,3) $.

Comment: If you have understood the proof given in text (based on set $A$), then the problem is trivial. If you think the problem is non-trivial then it is time to revisit the proof given in text and convince yourself that each and every part of the proof is clearly understood (let us know if there are any issues here).